# Excel: create a formatted table for easy autofill

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to print individual salary sheet for each staff, is there a way to create individual tables with values still reference to the main statistic table everytime i autofill them down?

Comment: This looks like an easy question to answer: yes, it's possible. It probably gets harder once you disclose what you are auto-filling but, of course, you can fill new tables with references to an existing one. You may be wanting a template where you enter an employee reference and a date at the top and all cells fill with appropriate data from the master table. That would be done with VLOOKUP

Comment: You can have a look on this video tutorial on youtube. [Salary Pay Slip Generation.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0kV8V7kpT0)